# Possible to check if less than 768px width and scroll to the certain px before adding class navbar-fixed-top?

Tags: jquery

```
var width = $(window).width();
var navHeight = $('.navbar').height() //100px;
var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();

function scrollAddClass(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if (scroll > navHeight){
            $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        }
        else{
            $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        }
    });
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    var navHeight = $('.navbar').height();
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (width < 768) {
        console.log('resize');
        scrollAddClass();
    }
});
```

Wanted to add navbar-fixed-top class only when scroll down beyond 100px in mobile screen.

console.log shows 'resized' but the scroll part is not working. Searched but most of the answers use scroll without resize.

Is there a way around this? Or scroll is the only way without resize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably want to move

```
var navHeight = $('.navbar').height() //100px;
var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
```

right before

```
if (scroll > navHeight){
```

(inside the scroll event)